# SQL How to add a value in a new column from another row

Tags: sql

I have a table with results of exams for students. Each exam has his row and I d like to have a single row for each student with all results ...
For example :

```
Student1 : email : school : comment : result1
Student1 : email : school : comment : result2
...
```

Must be :

```
Student1 : email : school : comment : result1 : result2
```

Many thanks !

Comment: No of exams are fixed or changes for each student?

Comment: How depends on which dbms, but you are looking for a cross tab or pivot query

Comment: Thanks for your interest ... I use SQL2008r2. I already read a lot about pivot but in all examples I find there is an aggregate function but I don't need this (?)

Answer (score 0):

You need alterate your table

Maybe the option is create a new table a then copy the data into the new table

```
CREATE TABLE NEWTABLE (Student1 Varchar(130), email Varchar(130), 
school Varchar(80), comment Varchar(255), result1 FLOAT, result2 FLOAT);
```

THEN

```
INSERT INTO NEWEXAM 
SELECT (Student1 , email , school , comment , result1, '') FROM OLDTABLE
```